# textbox validation input format

Tags: c#, validation

i just want to validate the user input in textbox.
so here's the thing.I want to Validate textbox.text format should only accept "00-00000"
if has child "00-00000-az... and so on".

so if the user will input even without - sign it will automaticall validate the format.
example: if the user input is 18999231
the result must be: 18-99923-1
so it will be like that.
it will make easy if it's the input value.
the other problem here is if the user will input 18-79-aa
the validation for that would be 18-00079-aa

i have in mind that if the user will input it will automatically display the - sign after inputting 2 first number and will auto fill also the zero if the user will not input the exact 5 numbers but it will display after the first - sign. and lastly is when the user input exceed the 2nd 5 numbers the next letter or number that the user will be display next in 2nd - sign that will automatically fill if the user input will exceed the 2nd 5 numbers after the first - sign.

the problem is i dont know the code yet

Comment: You are going to have to do a lot of work on the text change event (or preview text change, depending if its wpf or winforms), knowing where the cursor is, and possible regex to valid the result at any point. However since you havent attempted any code, this question will probably not last long as there is 100s of options variables and ways to do this

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use string.format

string.format can easily transform your text input.

```
String.Format("{0:##-#####-#}", 18999231);
```

Result: 18-99923-1

2.

```
        string input = "18-79-aa";
        string[] numbers = input.Split('-');
        int fixednumber = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[1]);
        string value = fixednumber.ToString("D5");
        string output = numbers[0] + "-" + value + "-" + numbers[2];
```

Result: 18-00079-aa

Comment: thanks a lot i'll try your suggestion. i just have another question . base in second option. if the user will input just like this 18-79aa the result would be 18-017aa right? i have a solution for this if you know the code that will count the - sign or there split. if it is 2 - sign it will go to the second option but if it is just one - sign it will check either the - sign is after the first 2 number or after the 5 numbers. can you suggest a code for me please.

Comment: and also i got an error in string fixednumber = numbers[1].ToString("D5");

Comment: you can count '-' sign how many times included, then which way choose.

Comment: oh i made mistake, you can try now. I'm fixed